# QgsTask and thread safety in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.8.2.

I subclassed QgsTask in order to process jobs that make class to a postgres database outputs the data as a kmz or shapefile. When I execute the run method directly, everything works fine albeit it blocks the main thread.

```
         task = CbydTask(job_queue, context, output_dir)
         task.run()
```

If I kick off a bunch of them and send them to the task manager for processing, many of them will finish but eventually and very randomly QGIS will crash. It will crash either two or three jobs in. Or almost at the end of all the jobs. It is not consistent on which jobs it fails on and all jobs will process correctly when just doing task.run().

```
        manager = QgsApplication.taskManager()
        for job in job_queue:
            manager.addTask(CbydJobTask(job, context, output_dir))
```

When I opened visual studio to try and get deeper debug info, I saw messages like

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBE9DCB049 (ntdll.dll) in qgis-bin.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FFBE9E327F0).

and

0x00007FFB959DF1F6 (QtCore.pyd) in qgis-bin.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

None of the objects referenced in the QgsTask class references the UI in any way nor attempts to communicate with the main thread other than the normal signals between the task and the task manager.

The class definition is below:

```
class CbydJobTask(QgsTask):

    def __init__(self, job, context, output_dir):
        QgsTask.__init__(self, '811 Export Job ' + str(job.get_id()))
        """Constructor."""

        self.job = job
        self.context = context
        self.output_dir = output_dir

    def run(self):
        """Start the job-building/validation routine."""

        self.setProgress(0)
        if self.isCanceled():
            return False
        if self.context['kmz']:
            self.job.set_strategy(CbydKmzStrategy())
            self.job.process(self.output_dir)

        if self.isCanceled():
            return False

        if self.context['shp']:
            if self.job.is_buffered():
                self.job.set_strategy(CbydBufferedShpStrategy())
            else:
                self.job.set_strategy(CbydShpStrategy())
            self.job.process(self.output_dir)

        if self.isCanceled():
            return False

        if self.context['utilisphere']:
            self.job.set_strategy(CbydBufferedShpUtilisphereStrategy())
            self.job.process(self.output_dir)

        self.setProgress(1)

        return True
```

job.process() just delegates to the strategy class's build() function. If there is one that may not have something thread safe in it, I guess it could be this one. I will open up a thread on stack exchange. But if where I messed up is glaringly obvious, please let me know.

```
class CbydShpStrategy(CbydAbstractStrategy):

    SPATIAL_QUERY = #QUERY REMOVED FOR EXAMPLE
    DATA_QUERY = #QUERY REMOVED FOR EXAMPLE

    def _prepare_output_path(self, output_dir, company, state, code):

        output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, company, state, code, 'SHAPE')
        if not os.path.isdir(output_path):
            os.makedirs(output_path)

        return output_path

    def build(self, id, output_dir):

        data = None
        with psycopg2.connect(DSN_ODW_RW, cursor_factory=RealDictCursor) as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(self.DATA_QUERY, (id,))
                data = cursor.fetchone()

        output_path = self._prepare_output_path(output_dir, data['company'], data['state'], data['code'])

        layer = QgsVectorLayer('MultiLineString?crs=epsg:'+
                               data['output_coord_system']+
                               '&field=ductbankid:integer',data['code_type'],'memory')
        provider = layer.dataProvider()
        fields = layer.fields()

        spatial_data = None
        with psycopg2.connect(DSN_ODW_RW, cursor_factory=RealDictCursor) as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(self.SPATIAL_QUERY, (data['output_coord_system'], data['state'], data['code']))
                spatial_data = cursor.fetchall()

        features = []      
        for conduit in spatial_data:
            q = QgsFeature(fields)
            q['ductbankid'] = conduit['ductbankid']
            q.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(conduit['wkt_text']))
            features.append(q)

        provider.addFeatures(features)
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
            layer,
            os.path.join(output_path, data['file_name_shp']),
            'utf-8',
            driverName='ESRI Shapefile'
        )
```

Am I doing something that is not thread-safe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain you have already either solved the problem or forgot about the whole thing. However, for future readers I'm suggesting it's the QgsVectorFileWriter. I think it opens a new background thread (asynchronous) but the new thread can not access your vector layer as your task has already completed and your layer ceased to exist.

As a fix I would try implementing a `finished` method for your task and move the writing phase there. That should be a thread-safe place for it.

However, this is somewhat speculative as I'm not an expert either. I've just noticed somewhat similar behavior.